# App doesn't save date to calendar

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, ekeventstore

I am trying to save specific date to calendar but it doesn't work,I am using specific data and change it to string 
when I use current date its work! but not with specific .
This is my code:

```
@IBAction func addToCalenderButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    self.event?.Start
    let dateString = "Thu, 24 Oct 2015 07:45"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyy hh:mm"
    let date:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyy hh:mm"


    if (EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Event) != EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: {
            granted, error in
            self.createEvent(eventStore, title: (self.event?.title)!, startDate: date)
        })
    } else {
        createEvent(eventStore, title: (self.event?.title)!, startDate: date)
    }

}

func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate) {
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

    event.title = title
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
    do {
        try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
        savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier
        Constant.displayAlert(self, title: "", Message: "The event has been added")
    } catch {
       print("Bad things happened")
    }
}
```

Comment: Date format should be HH:mm and yyyy

Comment: I changed but not work @LeoDabus

Comment: Make sure you are getting a valid date. Also you should set a calendar for your date formatter

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyy hh:mm"
```

to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
```

Comment: Replace the top one